# Box shadow no funciona en dispositivos Iphone?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, box-shadow

Hola a todosestoy haciendo comprobaciones en mi portafolio personal, y  en mi formulario de contacto los input no tienen `border`, y en su lugar tienen un `box-shadow` que con el fondo crea un efecto muy chulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esos input, se visualizan correctamente en todos los dispositivos, incluso en la previsualización de chrome en móviles iphone, pero luego en teléfonos iphone me he dado cuenta que no se visualiza, y en tablet de apple imagino que ocurrirá lo mismo pero no tengo dispositivo para probar.

Lo curioso es que `box-shadow` se usa en más elemento de la web y estos sí se visualizan en dispositivos Iphone, así que no sé que puede estar pasando.
Al hacer click en los input para escribir estos están validados con JS, cambia de colores en caso de errores etc, ¿puede deberse a algo de JS el problema?

Así es como se ve en dispositivos Iphone:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente el código css está así:

```
.campo input{
padding: 1rem;
border: none;
border-radius: 20px;
width: 100%;
background-color: transparent;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px var(--secundario);  
outline: none;
color: var(--parrafos);}
```

Y el código HTML :

```
 <div class="contenedor" id="contacta">
            <form method="post" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-recaptcha="true">
                <input type="hidden" name="subject" 
                value="Mensaje desde el portfolio nombreficticio" />
                <div class="widget">
                    <h3>Contacta conmigo<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></h3>
                    
                    <div class="campo">
                        
                        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre *" name="nombre"autocomplete="off" >
                        <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="campo">
                        <input type="email" id="contact" placeholder="Email *" name="email" autocomplete="off">
                        <i class="fas fa-question"></i> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="campo">
                        <input type="text" id="asunto" placeholder="Asunto" name="asunto" autocomplete="off">
                        <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="campo">
                        <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje *" class="mensaje"></textarea>
                        <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="campo">
                        <div data-netlify-recaptcha="true"></div>
                    </div>
                
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="boton" name="envio" id="boton_submit">
                </div>
                
                
            </form>
            
        </div>
```

A ver que puede ser. Un saludo!

Comment: seguramente necesite un prefijo onda `-webkit-box-shadow`

Comment: Yo pensé lo mismo pero box-shadow me lo está cogiendo en otros elementos de la web bien, entonces no creo que eso vaya a influir, pero vamos que voy a probar, no pierdo nada jaja

Comment: tal vez necesite borde transparente y display block ( los input son medio especiales en algunos render engines ) de ultima aplica el efecto en un div contenedor

Comment: Encontré la solución en este enlace. ^^ https://discourse.webflow.com/t/box-shadow-not-working-properly-in-ios/123553 mismo problema que el mío.

Comment: podes auto responderte con el `-webkit-appearance: none;` como solución, luego de un tiempo le aceptas y ya queda

Answer (score 2):

Me contesto yo mismo por si alguien tiene el mismo problema que yo, resulta que esto ocurre cuando tratas un `box-shadow` en un input, tiene un comportamiento extraño en ios y la solución pasa por utilizar `-webkit-appearance:none;` en el selector donde esté el estilo del `box-shadow` en el input.
Página que me ayudó a obtener la solución: https://discourse.webflow.com/t/box-shadow-not-working-properly-in-ios/123553